Is it possible to automatically animate height: auto with css interpolate-size property?
I have this code and I would like to animate height when I add more text. Is it possible?


document.getElementById("append").addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += ' test test test test test test'
})
#text {
  height: auto;
  interpolate-size: allow-keywords;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}  
<button id="append">append</button>
<div id="text">test</div>




in your case, height is always auto so the transition is never triggered

@TemaniAfif Is it possible to trigger it somehow? What is the best way to solve this problem?

You could use JS to calculate the scroll height and set it as height.

" Interpolation between two intrinsic sizing keyword is not possible. One of both ends must be a length or percentage."

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/animate-to-height-auto#why_not_allow_intrinsic-size-keyword_in_calc
